# How to amend git commit message in post-receive hook

Tags: git, hook, githooks, git-post-receive

I need to modify commit messages in post-receive hook (add bug tracking id). Is there a graceful way to do it or do I have to script "git rebase -i" stuff?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393178/get-commit-message-in-git-hook

Comment: Scarcely related. I need to modify the comment in an automatic way, not just obtain it.

Comment: Sorry, meant this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823772/append-ticket-number-using-git-commit-hooks

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is specific to the post-receive hook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the commit message (or any other part of the commit) as the commit-ID is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit: changing any part of the commit changes the checksum, which means it's not the same commit anymore.  You can make a new, different commit (similar to `rebase -i`), or you can use notes, as already described.

Your best bet is generally to get the comment adjusted *before* making the commit in the first place.  Failing that, notes are designed to allow you to attach data after the fact.  Making a new commit from the old one can be made to work, but will be annoying: the developer who pushes the commit will have to obtain the new commit created by the post-receive hook.

Answer (score 0):

You have the possibility to add a note to your commit via git-notes. It will therefore not modify your commit. Nevertheless, it will not change your git commit message either.
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html

Comment: Thanks but I need to modify the comment (replace a template pattern within it).